# Cloning CodeIgniter's database object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a subquery library for CodeIgniter ([link to project](http://labs.nticompassinc.com/CodeIgniter-Subqueries/)), which works by returning database objects that you can use instead of the normal `$this->db` object.

Originally, I was making new database objects each time:

```
$this->CI =& get_instance();
$db = $this->CI->load->database('', true);
```

But I then realized (or rather someone pointed out to me) that this would make a new database connection each time!  So I decided to try to `clone` objects instead of making new ones.

I updated the code to look like so ([link to full code](https://github.com/NTICompass/CodeIgniter-Subqueries/blob/v3.0-beta/libraries/Subquery.php#L56)):

```
class Subquery{
    var $CI, $db;

    function __construct(){
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->db = $this->CI->db; // Default database connection
    }

    function start_subquery(){
        $newDatabase = clone $this->db;
        // some more code
        return $newDatabase;
    }
}
```

I tested this, and it seems to work, but I'm not sure if this solves the problem.  Does using `clone` make a new database connection, or does it use references internally and only keep one connection?

Comment: Unless `__clone()` is implemented in `->db`, it will use the same db connection resource afaik. Easily testable by setting & retrieving some user defined variable (not going to download CI to test that :P )

Comment: @Wrikken: Cool!  I've looked and it doesn't seem like there is a `__clone` method.  That's good.  I only want one connection :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, the `=&` is unnecessary and potentially harmful if you are not using PHP 4 (I assume `get_instance` returns an object).

As for whether `clone` creates a new connection .. this depends on the DB implementation.  As far as I can tell, `PDO` does not create an additional connection when it's cloned.  If you want to test this, create a small script that runs `start_subquery` to some effect and then sleeps for a decent amount of time.  Connect to mysql and run:

```
SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected'
```

If it's more than 2 (your connection to run the query and the one from your script) then an additional connection is being made for some reason.

As for *whether* you should clone the DB, I don't know why you would want to, but I don't really know the use case for this class nor do I know much about CI.

Comment: Note that Threads connected easily goes into the several hundred here in my production db... The 1 vs. 2 only works if you can guarantee you're the only one using the db at that moment. For MySQL, a `SET @var = 'test';` before cloning, and a `SELECT @var;` after cloning is safer (if it's 'test', the same connection is used).

Comment: @Wrikken true, I was assuming he would run it against his own mysql instance rather than on the production server

Comment: @Wrikken: I could test the `SHOW STATUS` on my local box, where there wouldn't hundreds of connections :-P

Comment: The `=&` is because that's how it's written in [CodeIgniter's docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html) (I never really thought about why it's there).  I clone the db because this is a subquery script for CodeIgniter's [active record class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html).  There is no built-in support for subqueries.  The clone is so that when you call `->select()` it won't interfere with the rest of the query.

Comment: Yep, a personal test database server would work (and should be used for this kind of thing.. but experience has taught me that 'testing in production' is anything but rare, hence the quick caveat ;) )

Comment: @RocketHazmat don't subqueries have to use the same connection?

Comment: @Wrikken: At work, I've tested in production.  Sometimes it responds differently than the test server.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: This class isn't actually running the subquery.  It's just using the active record methods to generate the SQL string.

Comment: Well, I presume you tested locally, found everything OK, worked up the chain like that, and finally did an integration test on the production db... Which is quite different then starting out there.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I see, so your concern is just that an extra DB connection would be created unnecessarily.  I assume the SQL string and connection are inextricably bound inside the DB oject then.

Comment: @Wrikken: something like that >.>;

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Someone pointed out to me that each time I call `$this->CI->load->database` I'm making a new connection, which is unnecessary.  So, I tried to fix it.  The db connection and query string are `private` (actually `protected`) variables that I can't access.